# is there a way to move the 3D Cursor on top of anything?

Tags: grease-pencil, 3d-cursor

Many times that I have converted a "View Space" Grease Pencil stroke to a curve, I have found that the curve was created and placed in where the 3D cursor is(not exactly but they have relationship).

However, I don't want the curve be placed inside any object(see fig below),I found no way to control "the deep" that where the curve will be placed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **Stroke Placement** to *Cursor*. Then left-click on an object to set the 3D cursor location and the Grease Pencil will be drawn in the plane of the 3D cursor.

[image]

If you don't want the 3D cursor to be placed on a surface, you can manually adjust its location in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel of the 3D View:

[image]